# getFilesDir() stops camera from completing action

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take a picture inside my application and save it to

```
Android/data/com.androidproject/files/Camera/photo.png
```

I was using this code

```
 private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File file = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir("Camera"),
                    "photo.png");               
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Log.v("FILE", "" + outputFileUri);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CALL_BACK);
        }

    }
```

and someone suggested that I change the line starting with `File file = ...` to

```
File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Camera" + File.separator + "photo.png");
file.mkdirs();
```

Which changes the path directory to what I wanted, *however* it also prevents the camera from completing the action. Meaning I click my button, the camera loads, I press the blue circle to snap the photo, then when I go to click the checkmark it does nothing. I can reload and retake the photo, or press x and cancel but I cannot select the checkmark.

Any ideas?

**edit**

After playing with it for a few hours I noticed something. When I go to click the checkmark and complete the photo taking operation there is a photo created in the folder. The checkmark doesn't close out the screen and go back to my activity but it creates a dummy type file. It's size is 0kb and its named "1092-309403.jpeg" not "photo.png". This file is also saved under "InternalStorage/DCIM/Camera". It's never fully saved though as my application never technically finishes the operation. As soon as I press x the picture deletes and its like it never happened. I also tried cleaning my project but that doesn't work.

Comment: If it worked prior to the change of the path without any other modifications, try cleaning your projects. In eclipse, the menu at the top, `Project` > `Clean`, this will recompile and regenerate everything from scratch.

Comment: @MattClark see edited question. The clean did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have folder named `photo.png` as leftover from your previous attempts. This prevents Camera app from creating a file with the same name. Check  Android/data/com.androidproject/files/Camera/ on the external storage and if there is a folder named `photo.png` there, delete it.

Comment: I just stuffed the file into the Android Gallery,  I never found out how to make this work

Answer (score 1):

Camera is a third party application and so it can not access your application's private storage. You have to give path to public storage. More information is here [Camera Intent not saving photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720383/camera-intent-not-saving-photo)

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar problem too, seems Android doesn't like internal storage... By the way, try with createTempFile():

```
File dir = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "Camera" );
File file = File.createTempFile( "photo.png",  ".jpg", dir );
```