# FileProvider Not Working with Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to make Camera App to store the output to my internal storage. I also understand that third party apps are not able to access the Internal Storage of my application **BUT** we are able to do so by exposing the internal directory through `FileProvider`. I have followed the guide here:

- [Camera Intent not saving photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720383/camera-intent-not-saving-photo)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

I specify my `AndroidManifest.xml` in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider" >

    <application>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_path" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I created a xml file named `file_provider_path.xml` in `/res/xml/`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="image_capture" path="public/" />
</paths>
```

This is how I create and call the Camera Intent:

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 5000;
private static final String CAMERA_FP_AUTHORITY = "com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.fileprovider";

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

Context context = MainActivity.this;
File imagePath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "public");
if (!imagePath.exists()) imagePath.mkdirs();
File newFile = new File(imagePath, "tmp.jpg");

Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, CAMERA_FP_AUTHORITY, newFile);
//context.grantUriPermission("com.google.android.GoogleCamera", imageUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Log.d("YouQi", "Image URI Passing to Camera: " + imageUri.toString());

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

When I run the application, I can get the below Logcat result:

```
    11-11 20:07:39.581 18303-18303/com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider D/YouQi: Image URI Passing to Camera: content://com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.fileprovider/image_capture/tmp.jpg
```

Right at the moment when the camera closes, I hit the below Exception:

```
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 19420
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{42e44f70 19420:com.google.android.GoogleCamera/u0a83} (pid=19420, uid=10083) that is not exported from uid 10312
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2882)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4544)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2274)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1425)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:906)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.PhotoModule.onCaptureDone(PhotoModule.java:1281)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.camera.PhotoModule$8.onClick(PhotoModule.java:593)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
com.google.android.GoogleCamera E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help to explain why the problem happen? I have created a sample project of my problem: http://www.axzae.com/downloads/CameraWithFileProvider.zip

Anyway, the app will work if I explicitly specify:

```
context.grantUriPermission(
    "com.google.android.GoogleCamera",
    imageUri,
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
);
```

But this will only work for nexus/cyanogen devices. Samsung camera app might use a different package name.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

1. Please do not try to put `exported="true"` as pointed out by `pskink`, your app will crash the moment it loads. FileProvider is not meant to work in this state.
2. Tried `intent.addFlags` solution by `CommonsWare`. Not working. probably will only works with `ACTION_SEND` kind of intent.
3. I found the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249007/how-to-use-support-fileprovider-for-sharing-content-to-other-apps). Apparently the manual granting way is the only solution. But we can always loop thru the list of candidate packages and grantPermission to all of them.

   ```
   List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
       String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
       context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   }
   ```

Comment: Very satisfying hack :)

Comment: `addFlags()` works on Android 5.0+. On older devices, your approach is required. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider for a sample.

Comment: I have a doubt here. I am sorry for my very less knowledge of Android, but I am confused. Before launching the camera, I am setting the directory as "Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES").   Do I still need to use FileProvider OR is it only used for images stored in private app area ?

Comment: @CommonsWare, your approach works as expected thanks. Also, I think that if you use intent.seClipData(ClipData.newRawUri(null, uri)); should also work.

Comment: Surprisingly, `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` worked for me on Android SDK 18 (version 4.3 Jellybean).

Comment: I also found that addFlags did not work on API 4.4 or below in this case for me. The "hack" specified in the answer here worked!

Comment: I had to do this only when trying to share with the gmail app. Other apps worked witthout this (Twitter, Facebook, Instagram, SMS). Anyone knows the reason behind such behavior?

Comment: @CommonsWare Will this solution work for Android 5.0+ versions also?

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat: As I wrote in [an earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650632/fileprovider-not-working-with-camera/33652695?noredirect=1#comment64274394_33652695), `addFlags()` is sufficient for Android 5.0+.

Comment: As @CommonsWare mentioned addFlags() works for Android 5.0+ and explicit URI permission works for versions below 5.0. One thing to remember If you are using the image capture intent as the question states, then you mostly expect a URI for the image captured. Be Aware that the data is null for versions below Android 6.0 if you set MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT. You are safe to use the URI you passed to the intent after checking the result is OK. So make sure to have a reference to the file URI for versions below Android 6

Comment: Also note that [Google's tutorial on how to take photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) doesn't use `addFlags()` at all so it's probably not needed any longer for recent Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but later on I find out to have a typo in my code. 
The typo was in AndroidManifest.xml, precisely into the  tag at the line "authorities".

For me,

```
android:authorities="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.fileprovider"
```

doesn't work (when I call the camera instance, the app crashes) but if i delete "file" and replace that string as following:

```
android:authorities="com.stackoverflow.test.camerawithfileprovider.provider"
```

my app runs smoothly (the app takes the photo, stores it, and gives back a preview to the activity in the client app).

Does your app also have the same issue ?