# Api 23 take picture without storage permissions

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to take pictures using the camera intent in api 23. I am requesting permission to use the camera intent but in an effort to limit the number of permission I need to check or ask for I don't want to save the picture in an app internal storage.  But passing file like this to the camera intent doesn't work. I am guessing cause the camera can't write to my apps storage.

```
  try {
        mTempImage = File.createTempFile("psn_temp", ".jpg", Controller.getContext().getCacheDir());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempImage));
```

if i do

```
File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    try {
                        mTempImage = File.createTempFile(
                                "psn_temp",  /* prefix */
                                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                                storageDir      /* directory */
                        );
```

this works but i have to ask for storage permission. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Context.getExternalFilesDir(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) for saving picture to your local external folder. Since KitKat (api 19) you dont need permissions to write to this external storage folder. Before api19 you had to require `​R​E​A​D​_​E​X​T​E​R​N​A​L​_​S​T​O​R​A​G​E​`, so if you want to support earlier apis add to your manifest:

```
​ ​ ​ ​<​u​s​e​s​-​p​e​r​m​i​s​s​i​o​n​ ​a​n​d​r​o​i​d​:​n​a​m​e​=​"​a​n​d​r​o​i​d​.​p​e​r​m​i​s​s​i​o​n​.​R​E​A​D​_​E​X​T​E​R​N​A​L​_​S​T​O​R​A​G​E​"​
 ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​a​n​d​r​o​i​d​:​m​a​x​S​d​k​V​e​r​s​i​o​n​=​"​1​8​"​
 ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​/​>​
```

you also dont need WRITE_* permission, since you are not writing - camera app is doing this.

For explanation why getCacheDir does not work look here:

[Camera Intent not saving photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720383/camera-intent-not-saving-photo)